# Ubuntu PC no longer starts up

Tags: boot, grub2

So, I noticed the boot partition was too big when running fsck from a live USB drive, so I resized it to make it smaller and resized the main partition to make it bigger. It was successful, but after rebooting the PC detected that there were no OSes. I then tried running boot-repair and still got the same error. I don't want to re-install Ubuntu, but what should I do to correct this?

Comment: Read this and try testdisk https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: What tool did you use to resize partitions? What does it mean that a partition was too big?

Comment: @Melebius I used GParted. Apparently the boot partition was 64GB for some reason...

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid this looks like a disk error. You should try a data recovery tool. **Do NOT do any arbitrary modifications!** Especially partition changes can make the recovery much more difficult…

Comment: @Melebius Just checked, the drive has an end-to-end error in SMART test, but seems to be intact data-wise.